# In Xamarin.IOS, adding constraint to view programmatically (using api code) doesn't set the right or bottom edges correctly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uikit

I have a subview *myTextView*, which has the right constraint set after adding the subview to the main view as shown below,

```
var myTextView = new UITextView();

// other View setup related codes...

View.AddSubview(myTextView);

// other constraint related codes...

var constTextViewRight = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
                             myTextView,
                             NSLayoutAttribute.Right,
                             NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
                             View,
                             NSLayoutAttribute.Right,
                             1,
                             20
                         );

View.AddConstraint(constTextViewRight);
```

but this won't set the right margin with 20 points. It stays attached with the parent view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here, when we are setting things relatively left to another element, we have to use negative values and in the same way if we are setting something relatively above another element then we have to use negative values. It's because **UIKit**, uses (0,0) origin as the Top Left corner of the Device. Hence the constraint creating code segment should be as below,

```
var constTextViewRight = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(
                             myTextView,
                             NSLayoutAttribute.Right,
                             NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
                             View,
                             NSLayoutAttribute.Right,
                             1,
                             -20
                         );
```

the **constant** parameter of the **NSLayoutConstraint.Create** method should be in negative points (-20 in this scenario).